# Can you change the desktop grid layout in KDE?

Tags: unity, kubuntu, multiple-monitors, kde, workspaces

I have recently switched from Ubuntu 14.04 to Kubuntu 14.04 and there's one thing that's bugging me...

I have two (identical) monitors and I use multiple workspaces extensively. My workspaces are arranged in two columns of four workspaces, like this:

```
+--------+--------+
|   #1   |   #2   |
+--------+--------+
|   #3   |   #4   |
+--------+--------+
|   #5   |   #6   |
+--------+--------+
|   #7   |   #8   |
+--------+--------+
```

When I used Ubuntu and I pressed the workspace grid hotkey (`META+S`), my monitors would be laid out like this (sorry for the big complicated ASCII diagrams):

```
+================Left Monitor================+  +===============Right Monitor================+
|                                            |  |                                            |
|   +--------+--------+ +--------+--------+  |  |   +--------+--------+ +--------+--------+  |
|   |  #1 L  |  #1 R  | |  #2 L  |  #2 R  |  |  |   |  #1 L  |  #1 R  | |  #2 L  |  #2 R  |  |
|   +--------+--------+ +--------+--------+  |  |   +--------+--------+ +--------+--------+  |
|   |  #3 L  |  #3 R  | |  #4 L  |  #4 R  |  |  |   |  #3 L  |  #3 R  | |  #4 L  |  #4 R  |  |
|   +--------+--------+ +--------+--------+  |  |   +--------+--------+ +--------+--------+  |
|   |  #5 L  |  #5 R  | |  #6 L  |  #6 R  |  |  |   |  #5 L  |  #5 R  | |  #6 L  |  #6 R  |  |
|   +--------+--------+ +--------+--------+  |  |   +--------+--------+ +--------+--------+  |
|   |  #7 L  |  #7 R  | |  #8 L  |  #8 R  |  |  |   |  #7 L  |  #7 R  | |  #8 L  |  #8 R  |  |
|   +--------+--------+ +--------+--------+  |  |   +--------+--------+ +--------+--------+  |
|                                            |  |                                            |
+============================================+  +============================================+
```

I could then drag windows from one workspace/monitor to another easily - the workspaces & monitors are laid out in a logical arrangement.

But in Kubuntu, the layout is different:

```
+======Left Monitor======+  +=====Right Monitor======+
|                        |  |                        |
|   +--------+--------+  |  |   +--------+--------+  |
|   |  #1 L  |  #2 L  |  |  |   |  #1 R  |  #2 R  |  |
|   +--------+--------+  |  |   +--------+--------+  |
|   |  #3 L  |  #4 L  |  |  |   |  #3 R  |  #4 R  |  |
|   +--------+--------+  |  |   +--------+--------+  |
|   |  #5 L  |  #6 L  |  |  |   |  #5 R  |  #6 R  |  |
|   +--------+--------+  |  |   +--------+--------+  |
|   |  #7 L  |  #8 L  |  |  |   |  #7 R  |  #8 R  |  |
|   +--------+--------+  |  |   +--------+--------+  |
|                        |  |                        |
+========================+  +========================+
```

Also logical, I guess, but it forces me to stop and think carefully about where I'm dragging a window in a way that I didn't have to under Unity. For example, if I want to drag a window from #3L (left monitor, #3 workspace) to #2R (right monitor, #2 workspace), I have to stop and think about exactly which workspace on the right monitor it needs to be dropped on.

Is there a way to reorganize the desktop grid under KDE to match that under Unity?

Comment: I love your asciis. xD

Comment: I never used another desktop than KDE, but I would prefer the unity arrangement as well.